# PHP phpMyAdmin error when trying to open

Tags: php, mysql, cookies, phpmyadmin, web-hosting

I have free account on [www.000webhost.com](http://www.000webhost.com) website. I had created database with 4 tables and uploaded some php files on file manager to use them as web services.
It worked well for two weeks, but now it is not working well and gives me error, then I cleared the browser history and cookies but when I am trying to open phpmyadmin it gives me this error:

> Error during session start; please check your PHP and/or webserver log file and configure your PHP installation properly. Also ensure that cookies are enabled in your browser.
>
> session_start(): open(SESSION_FILE, O_RDWR) failed: No space left on device (28)

How can I fix it, although the tables only contains 4 or 5 records only because I still test my work.

Comment: "No space left on device" -- pretty plain error message. Delete files until there's more space available.

Comment: But there is nothing a lot, I only have 10 php  files with size of 2 or 3 KB and only some records with about 10 MB

Comment: Then you need to contact the support for 000webhost.com. The free accounts are all hosted on shared servers, one of the other websites on the server your website is hosted on is probably using up too much space.

Comment: find a decent hosting provider.

Comment: i am also looking for this if anyone knows howto solve plz help i m using free account and using codeignetor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems it's temporary. On the Spanish-Foum of 000WebHost Community it's written that they know it:

There is known issue with phpMyAdmin you may get some odd errors popping up but the issue is being resolved.

session_start(): open(SESSION_FILE, O_RDWR) failed: No space left on device (28)

We are fixing it and sorry for any inconvenience; please do not create threads regarding it.

I have the same problem. Waiting for a solution by 000WebHost.

Comment: Yes I saw that, But do you know if this take long time or it will be ready today or tomorrow?

Comment: phpMyAdmin - Error
Error during session start; please check your PHP and/or webserver log file and configure your PHP installation properly. Also ensure that cookies are enabled in your browser.

session_start(): open(SESSION_FILE, O_RDWR) failed: No space left on device (28)


I am also facing this issue not able to resoved